# Grails hasMany and criteria not working as expected

Tags: grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I have two models with a hasMany relation

```
class Puturru implements Serializable {
    String name

    Set<Fua> fuas

    static hasMany = [fuas: Fua]

    static constraints = {
        fuas(nullable: true)
    }
}
```

And

```
class Fua {

    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

When running the next test I'm getting a LazyInitializationException

```
 void "test something"() {
    given:
    def puturrus

    Puturru.withNewSession { session ->
        p = Puturru.build()
        Fua f
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            f = Fua.build()
            p.addToFuas(f)
        }
        f.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)

    }

    when:
    Puturru.withNewSession {

        puturrus = Puturru.createCriteria().listDistinct {

            fetchMode("fuas", FetchMode.JOIN)
        }

    }

    then:
    Puturru.withNewSession {
        assert puturrus.fuas*.name.size() > 0

    }

    p.fuas.each { it.delete() }
    p.delete()
}
```

If I set puturrus mapping

```
static mapping = {
    fuas lazy: false
}
```

Then all the elements are retrieved although it uses multiple selects, otherwise it use this query

```
select ...
from puturru ...
left outer join puturru_fua fuas2_ on this_.id=fuas2_.puturru_fuas_id
```

I can't set mapping in the real app, because I don't want to fetch all entries in all cases. To me looks like I'm missing something to make the criteria go further than the intermediate table.

I'm using grails 2.3.6 and hibernate 3.6.10.8.

Do somebody know why is not getting the "fuas" objects?

### EDIT 1: Some more information

I have been trying to do some changes to the domains and test aiming to figure out what the problem is.

After @sudhir suggestion, I started playing with joins I changed the criteria to something like

```
    puturrus = Puturru.createCriteria().listDistinct {
        fuas {
        }
    }
```

Then the query generated by gorm and hibernate was

```
select ...
from puturru this_
inner join puturru_fua fuas3_ on this_.id=fuas3_.puturru_fuas_id
inner join fua fuas_alias1_ on fuas3_.fua_id=fuas_alias1_.id
```

This time we got all the entries but not their relations with the puturrus domains. We compromise and put a second query just for getting the associations, so for the time being the second session block is

```
Puturru.withNewSession {

    puturrus = Puturru.createCriteria().listDistinct {
        fuas {
        }
    }

    Puturru.createCriteria().listDistinct {
        fetchMode("fuas", FetchMode.JOIN)
    }
}
```

This is way better than my previous approach that was iterate over all the puturrus and all the fuas within the criteria session, but I think is still sub-optimal, so are there any way to get both the data and the associations in a single query?

Comment: You are not saving Putturu at the end of given: block.
Why are you using withNewSession at all this places, its not required at all. Also, beaware, fetchmode join can give you duplicate results, you may want to use fetchmode FM.SELECT

Comment: Actually build method, which is part of build test data plugin, save. I made this code just to reproduce a situation I found in a real world app, in the real world there are good reasons to split the three sessions. I tried FM.SELECT too with no success.

Comment: Try adding join 'fuas' in your criteria, and remove fetchMode, so it would be like criteria.listDistinct { join "fuas"}

Comment: @sudhir if I do so, the query has two inner joins, but still doesn't work. However if I inspect the elements with a debugger, this query  `select fuas0_.puturru_fuas_id as puturru1_1_0_, fuas0_.fua_id as fua2_0_ from puturru_fua fuas0_ where fuas0_.puturru_fuas_id=?` and then the elements are available out of the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a proper solution using createAlias

```
Puturru.withNewSession {
    puturrus = Puturru.createCriteria().listDistinct {
        createAlias("fuas", "fuas", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    }
}
```

Actually it seems to be a bug in Hibernate 3.6 already fixed in Hibernate 4

Answer (score 0):

You can use following hql

```
Puturru.executeQuery("select p from Puturru p inner join fetch p.fuas as f where p.id = :id", [id:id])
```

If you want all Puturru remove where condition

Comment: You're right, that would be useful is the code were so simple like this examples, but the real code is much more complex and it includes several other domains, and we don't want such a big hql query.